# How to continue a Jenkins build even though a build step failed?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process, jenkins, phing

I am using a Phing build script with Jenkins and would like to run it end to end on a job and capture all the reports. The problem is it stop building on a failed build step. Is there a way or a plugin that would continue the job even on failures?

Thanks

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497452/subant-failonerror-subtleties

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about Phing but, since it's based on Ant, if the build step you are executing has a "failonerror" attribute you should be able to set it to false so that the entire build doesn't fail if the step returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use try, catch block in you pipeline scripts

example:

```
try {
    // do some stuff that potentially fails
} catch (error) {
    // do stuff if try fails
} finally {
    // when you need some clean up to do
}
```

Or alternatively if you use sh commands to run these tests, consider running your sh scripts with the "|| true" suffix, this tells the linux sh script to exit with a result code of 0, even if your real command exited with an exit code.

example:

```
stage('Test') {
    def testScript = ""
    def testProjects = findFiles(glob: 'test/**/project.json')

    if (!fileExists('reports/xml')) {
        if (!fileExists('reports')) {
            sh "mkdir reports"
        }
        sh "mkdir reports/xml"
    }

    for(prj in testProjects) {
        println "Test project located, running tests: " + prj.path
        def matcher = prj.path =~ 'test\\/(.+)\\/project.json'

        testScript += "dotnet test --no-build '${prj.path}' -xml 'reports/xml/${matcher[0][1]}.Results.xml' || true\n"
    }

    sh testScript
```