# How can I force update code coverage trend graphs on failed jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco

How can I publish the results of the code coverage to the trend graph even if the job fails after the jacoco analysis? 
For Findbugs, PMD, etc. this can be achieved with the `canRunOnFailed` setting. Is there something similar for JaCoCo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On project level I see the trend graph which only considers the successful builds. I would also like to see the coverage graph updated if the job fails.

This is tracked by [JENKINS-28479](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28479):

> ### ProjectActions (and trend graphs) do not appear for failed projects
>
> This problem is not only related to the JUnit plug-in. In general, every plug-in that has been migrated its actions to a SimpleBuildStep has this problem. The affected source code is in **[`SimpleBuildStep`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/8242e0eb1625454ae5539c444c8d8ecf99a70b62/core/src/main/java/jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep.java#L119-L121)**.
>
> A test case that exposes this bug is [WarningsPluginTest#should_not_skip_failed_builds_with_option_run_always](https://github.com/jenkinsci/acceptance-test-harness/blob/master/src/test/java/plugins/WarningsPluginTest.java#L619)

This is still open.

---

Original answer:

This is not specific to the maven jacoco build step: all you need to do is make sure that build step always return "success".

If you are using pipelines, you can [wrap your step in a try/catch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423989/6309).

If you are using a regular job definition, you could consider a [shell/windows command step where you return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745593/6309) (or `exit /b 0`) *after* the mvn command.

The next build step would be the `mvn sonar:sonar` publication one, which will then always be executed.

Comment: Sorry I was not specific enough. The JaCoCo results are published, I can see the results in job execution. However on project level I see the **trend graph** which only considers the successful builds. I would also like to see the coverage graph updated if the job fails.

Comment: @Christopher OK. I have edited the answer accordingly, with a reference to the relevant Jenkins issue.

Comment: Not a satisfying answer, but at least I now know where to look if the issue was fixed. Thanks.