# How to upload to dropbox even with build failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dropbox

I am using Jenkins as CI tool and it builds my project and upload the build result to dropbox through dropbox plugin. I added a Post Build Action "Send build artifacts over Dropbox.". This action will be triggered if all build and test case steps are passed. But I want to upload to dropbox even the test cases failed. How can I configure that on jenkins dropbox plugin?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421424/how-to-continue-a-jenkins-build-even-though-a-build-step-failed?

Comment: This is about modifying pipeline script and I don't want to do that. My project is all configured through jenkins UI without writing any scripts. Is there a way to achieve this by configuring?