# Child build failure not making parent build fail in Ant

Tags: ant

I am calling child `build.xml` from parent `build.xml` by using `subant`:

```
 <target name="deploy-vc-orgstr">
    <subant target="deploy" failonerror="true">
      <fileset dir="${orgstr.vc.home}" includes="build.xml"/>
    </subant>
  </target>
```

When I get compilation errors from child build.xml, my parent build still shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL. In logs I can see compilation errors while building target "deploy-vc-orgstr".

How to make parent build fail on child build failure?

Actually I have two targets defined.

```
target: deploy-vc-orgstr
target: deploy
```

I want if target "deploy-vc-orgstr" get fails then target "deploy" should also get fail.

My build.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<!--Ant buildfile generated by Oracle JDeveloper-->
<!--Generated Nov 1, 2012 5:00:36 PM-->
<project name="SafetyExcellenceManagementSystem" default="deploy" basedir=".">
  <property file="build.properties"/>
  <!--Change to include model build Starts -->
<target name="deploy-vc-orgstr">
        <subant target="deploy" failonerror="true">
          <fileset dir="${orgstr.vc.home}" includes="*/build.xml"/>
        </subant>
      </target>
  <target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${output.dir}"/>
  </target>
  <target name="deploy" description="Deploy JDeveloper profiles"
          depends="init,deploy-vc-orgstr">
    <taskdef name="ojdeploy"
             classname="oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.ant.OJDeployAntTask"
             uri="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
             classpath="${oracle.jdeveloper.ant.library}"/>
    <ora:ojdeploy xmlns:ora="oraclelib:OJDeployAntTask"
                  executable="${oracle.jdeveloper.ojdeploy.path}"
                  ora:buildscript="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.dir}/ojdeploy-build.xml"
                  ora:statuslog="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.dir}/ojdeploy-statuslog.xml">
      <ora:deploy>
        <ora:parameter name="workspace"
                       value="${oracle.jdeveloper.workspace.path}"/>
        <ora:parameter name="profile"
                       value="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.profile.name}"/>
        <!--ora:parameter name="nocompile" value="true"/-->
        <ora:parameter name="outputfile"
                       value="${oracle.jdeveloper.deploy.outputfile}"/>
      </ora:deploy>
    </ora:ojdeploy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497452/subant-failonerror-subtleties

Comment: Hi Eugen,I have edited my question. Can you please help now.